# Quantity decrease from prestashop supplier

Tags: prestashop, product, stock

How to change the logic for a stock decrease in PrestaShop? 
Instead of stock decrease from stock_available table, we want to change it from product_supplier table.
we want to show out stock if in product_supplier table the stock is 0.
What will be the best approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented the quantity field in the table presta_product_supplier.
for that, we created one trigger which is decreasing the stock for that product of particular supplier.